# Error on corda webservice startup

Tags: corda

We have an error in one of our nodes when we tried to start corda webservice:

We get following error:

[ERROR] 2018-04-06T10:54:45,575Z [main] Main.main - Exception during node startup
net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException: Please specify a `PageSpecification` as there are more results [201] than the default page size [200]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:234) ~[corda-rpc-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.vaultTrack(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.legalcontract.api.LegalContractApi.(LegalContractApi.kt:73) ~[kotlin-source.jar:?]
    at com.legalcontract.plugin.LegalContractPlugin$webApis$1.invoke(LegalContractPlugin.kt:18) ~[kotlin-source.jar:?]
    at com.legalcontract.plugin.LegalContractPlugin$webApis$1.invoke(LegalContractPlugin.kt:12) ~[kotlin-source.jar:?]
    at com.legalcontract.plugin.LegalContractPluginKt$sam$Function$b4d51671.apply(LegalContractPlugin.kt) ~[kotlin-source.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.buildServletContextHandler(NodeWebServer.kt:147) ~[corda-webserver-impl-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.initWebServer(NodeWebServer.kt:75) ~[corda-webserver-impl-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.start(NodeWebServer.kt:45) ~[corda-webserver-impl-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.WebServer.main(WebServer.kt:64) [corda-webserver-impl-2.0.0.jar:?]
Caused by: net.corda.core.node.services.VaultQueryException: Please specify a `PageSpecification` as there are more results [201] than the default page size [200]

Do you know what could be the problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a fail-fast mode when the vault is queried and too many results are returned, to prevent the vault query loading thousands or millions of states at once.

See https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html#pagination.

You have to specify a pagination as follows:

```
val vaultSnapshot = proxy.vaultQueryBy<ContractState>(
    QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED),
    PageSpecification(DEFAULT_PAGE_NUM, 200))
```